# ¿Cómo detecto e imprimo los strings dentro de una lista?

Tags: python, lista

Dada una lista con diferentes variables, necesito detectar e imprimir sólo los strings:

```
lista = [10, 'python', 3, 'UOC', True]
```

Quiero hacerlo con un codigo 'for', primero entiendo que tengo que recorrer la lista:
Primero tendré que crear una variable sólo para los strings:

```
s = []

for x in lista:
    s.append(str(x))
    print(x)
```

Soy primeriza con programación y no se como conseguirlo, me da error todo el rato. Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: la clave aquí es validar si una variable es de tipo str o no. ¿Sabes hacerlo?

Answer (score 3):

Puedes utilizar isinstance, de esta forma:

```
lista = [10, 'python', 3, 'UOC', True]
s = []

for x in lista:
   if isinstance(x, str):
       s.append(x)

print(s)
```

Comment: ´isinstance(x,str)´ devuelve si es un string o si el tipo de dato de x hereda de string.
para conseguir el tipo de dato de `x` seria `type(x)` por lo tanto si quieres reconocer solo string y no clases que heredan de string seria `type(x) == str`

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando el `for` loop:

```
lista = [10, 'python', 3, 'UOC', True]

s = []
for i in lista:
    if(type(i) == str):
        s.append(i)
```

Sin embargo Python tiene algo llamado **Listas por comprensión** que son muy utiles para lo que quieres hacer por ejemplo

```
[i for i in lista if type(i) == str]
```

Y por cierto, si quisieras verificar que el tipo es `str` e `int`, te animo a utilizar `in` en lugar de una cadena de `==` y `or`

```
[i for i in lista if type(i) in [str, int]]
```

que equivale a

```
[i for i in lista if type(i) == str or type(i) == int]
```